# Method [postSigin] does not exist - Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, phpstorm

Method [postSignin] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\UserController].
I'm trying to create a login in form. The signup worked but when I sign in, I get this error.
I'm now getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or '

**Here is my Route:**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);

Route::post('/signin', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin'
]);

Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
]);
```

**My controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
```

}

**UserController:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function getDashboard()
{
    return view('dashboard');
}

public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request['email'];
    $first_name = $request['first_name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->first_name = $first_name;
    $user->password = $password;

    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}

public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }
   return redirect()->back();
}
public function method(Request $req)
{
    dd($req->all();
}
```

}

**And my blade:**

```
<form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="post">
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Show your `web.php` with routes

Comment: Have you the `postSignin` in the controller ?

Comment: @Maraboc Yes I have it. if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) { return redirect()->route('dashboard');

Comment: And in your route you have some thing like this `route::post('signin',UserController@postSignin)->name('signin');` ?

Comment: @Maraboc Route::post('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@method',
        'as' => 'signin'

Comment: post some relevent code like your route file and user controller

Comment: This is the problem you have to use the `postSignin` not `method` like this : `Route::post('/signin', [ 'uses' => 'UserController@postSignin', 'as' => 'signin']);` !

Comment: @Sohel0415 just updated my post. Check it

Comment: add your UserController

Comment: @Sohel0415 Updated

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

in you web.php

```
route::post('signin','UserControllerr@method')->name('signin');
```

in your App\Http\Controllers\UserController add like this

```
public function method(Request $req){
    dd($req->all();
}
```

Comment: I replaced method with @postSignIn. Now I'm getting: Method [method] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\UserController]."

Comment: @pinealda upadted my answer please check

Comment: do I put method or SignIn? and it is expecting ','

Comment: @pinealda updated my answer check

Comment: i'm not sure what you updated.. I have  public function method(Request $req)
    {
        dd($req->all();
    }    And I get same error.

Comment: @pinealda updated my answer please check

Comment: Im sorry but Idk what have you updated because I put the same code as you first post and its been same since.. Check my updated post.

Comment: @pinealda if you seen carefully you last line of user controller code has error dd($req->all(); here missing is ) so change it to dd($req->all()); .. if you getting error in controller your browser will display error line number. In your case it giving syntax error  dd($req->all(); here missing is ) so change it to dd($req->all());